# What are the two best iphone and blackberry development books you have read?

Tags: iphone, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I want to hit the ground running at a new firm. I am seasoned developer in Java/C so will pick up things fast. Need to be able to follow tutorials. I can do either video or plain text. Need your expert advice in recommending a good book to me.

Thank You for your time.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the best beginning iPhone book around is "Beginning iPhone Development" by Mark and LaMarche.  Here is a link to the newest version [here](http://apress.com/book/view/9781430224594).  A companion book that was useful to me (never having done objective-c before) was "Learn Objective-C on the Mac" by Dalrymple and Knaster and also published by aPress. [here](http://apress.com/book/view/1430218150).

I have no knowledge with regards to blackberry books so hopefully someone else can point you in the right direction there.

Comment: thought i would add that i also read the books mentioned above as a Java/C programmer.

Answer (score 1):

must read blackberry java development books

[Beginning BlackBerry Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430272252)

[Advanced BlackBerry Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430226560)

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Jesse Naugher about [Beginning iPhone Development](http://www.apress.com/book/view/9781430224594) by Mark & Lamarche.  I read it as a Java/C developer without any knowledge of Objective-C beforehand and didn't have any problems.

For BlackBerry there's [Beginning BlackBerry Development](http://www.apress.com/book/view/1430272252) (I'm obviously biased here, but it is written for developers with just a background in Java, and has been well received, and is still the best-selling BlackBerry development book).  To be a bit more balanced, I'll also mention [BlackBerry Development Fundamentals](http://bbdevfundamentals.com/) by John Wargo, which is broader - i.e. discusses web apps and BlackBerry solution architecture - but doesn't go as deep into developing Java-based apps for BlackBerry.  Also very accessible and very well written.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Jesse Naugher. 
Also, to get a slightly different perspective:
I would recommend [iPhone Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide](http://www.bignerdranch.com/book/iphone_programming_the_big_nerd_ranch_guide)
Get the [Kindle version](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003EINO1W) for [your Mac - Kindle for Mac](http://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html/ref=kcp_mac_mkt_lnd?docId=1000464931)
 
[alt text http://img408.imageshack.us/img408/3245/bnr.th.jpg](http://img408.imageshack.us/img408/3245/bnr.th.jpg)